CSS not loading in Jekyll Jekflix site
Link to repo: github.com/vishalscodes/shashiks-webpage 
Link to website: shashiks.netlify.app
The CSS seems to not be loading, despite the SASS compiling and it seems that none of the link tags are working. Please help.
I've tried adding various baseurl and url in the config yml files, but they don't work. I've also tried compiling the SASS with live sass compiler.

Make sure that it is included in the header of each page on the site.
E.g.
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">

